# Exponential Modulus solving large numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

How can a large number be calculated without using a calculator:

(6553719^8 + 6553719^8 + 6553719^8) MOD 10

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: Hi Guys, Been pulling my hair out on this one. Maths is not a strong point for me - Even the solution (hint!) provided below does kind of thickens the plot for me. I have tried to use the equation ----                                             a  x  b mod n = (a mod n)  x (b mod n) mod n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $a^8 \equiv b^8 \mod 10$ if $a \equiv b \mod 10$.

Further hint: use $-1$, not $9$.

Comment: Many thanks, Maths is not a strong point for me - Even the solution (hint!) provided does kind of thicken the plot for me. I have tried to use the equation ---- a x b mod n = (a mod n) x (b mod n) mod n

Comment: Why -1?, if it were 8 would it be -2?

Comment: $653719 \equiv -1 \mod 10$.

Comment: I am really not understanding the -1 element of the solution. 653719 mod 10 = 9 . To help me better understand what if it the number was 653711

Comment: "$\ldots \equiv \ldots \mod 10$" is a relation, not an operation.  $a \equiv b \mod 10$ means the difference $a-b$ is divisible by $10$.  $653719 \equiv 9 \mod 10$ is true, but so is $653719 \equiv -1 \mod 10$.